# How to extract and replace pattern in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract numbers at the end of the string using `regexec`

```
y <- c("abcd-efgh/xyz/123456789", "123456789", "abcd-efgh", "123456789")
m <- regexec("\\d+$", y)
new_y <- unlist(regmatches(y, m))
```

Final value of `new_y` looks like this

```
> new_y
[1] "123456789" "123456789" "123456789"
```

But I want it to look like this.

```
> new_y
[1] "123456789" "123456789" NA "123456789"
```

i.e. It should have NA value wherever it couldn't find the specified pattern.
Can anyone tell me how to do this or suggest me another way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
new_y = gsub("^.*[^0-9]","",y)
new_y[new_y == ""] <- NA
```

or if you want to use `regexpr`, then:

```
start <- regexpr("([0-9]+$)",y)
new_y = substr(y,
               ifelse(start>0,start,NA),
               nchar(y))
```

Comment: Using [stringr](https://github.com/hadley/stringr):


    
    `library("stringr");
    y <- c("abcd-efgh/xyz/123456789", "123456789", "abcd-efgh", "123456789");
    str_extract(y, "\\d+$");`

returns

`#> "123456789" "123456789" NA          "123456789"`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
ifelse(grepl("[[:digit:]]", y) == TRUE, gsub("[^[:digit:]]","", y), NA)
```